# Seat occupancy sensor malfunction VW Jetta 2008

Tags: vw, sensor, supplemental-restraint-system, seat

I have a problem with the passenger seat occupancy sensor. It doesn't understand if someone is seating and the seat belt warning light doesn't turn on if the passenger is not wearing his seat belt. Assuming that the passenger wears his seat belt, in case of a collision will the airbag deploy? My car is a VW Jetta 2008. The manual doesn't describe this case so I want to know if I should replace this part or it doesn't worth the money.

EDIT:
I went to my mechanic and he said that in order the airbag to be deployed it needs only to sense that the passenger is buckled up. Is there any vw standard to reference?

Comment: The problem most likely isn't the sensor, but the wiring *going to the sensor*. Many vehicles have this issue on the passenger's seat. This can be caused due to people having their feet under the seat (from the rear seat) or foreign matter (ie: water bottle rolled under the seat) which tugs/stretches the wiring and causes connection issues. This same connection is also strained when the seat is moved forward/backwards.

Comment: I have already checked this and everything seems to be connected. I will get someone to sit on the seat and check the continuity with a multimeter. But i think that the cable must be worn somewhere. Anyway I'll check everything

Comment: PAULSTER2 you were correct. The wire was worn. I replaced it. And everything is working now perfectly

Comment: Glad you were able to get it taken care of ... nothing worse than a faulty SRS, lol! J/K ... getting into an accident without the SRS functioning is probably worse ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The airbag won't deploy.

Because an inflating airbag is much more dangerous to children than to adults, seat sensors are used to determine if an adult is in the seat. If an adult is there, the airbag is enabled. If the seat contains a weight less than that of an adult — as, for example, a child occupies the seat — the airbag won't deploy (or, in some modern vehicles, will deploy at reduced force).

Your front-seat passengers are at risk. You should have the sensor fixed asap.